# I'd like to code the array value I received from Python into JS and print it out on the web page

Tags: javascript, python, plotly

It is to draw a plot graph on a web page using Python and js code.

Here's my python code

```
from bottle import route, run, request, redirect, template
import pymysql as sql

@route('/print')
def show_print():
    db = sql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='1234', db='testdb')
    if db is None:
        return template("index.tpl", text="Non", x_value=[], y_value=[])
    else:
        query = "select * from testdata;"
        cur = db.cursor()
        n = cur.execute(query)
        tpl_no=[]
        tpl_date=[]
        tpl_hum=[]
        tpl_tmp=[]
        for i in range(n):
            value = cur.fetchone()
            
            tpl_no.append(value[0])
            
            tpl_hum.append(value[2]) 
        return template("index.tpl", x_value = tpl_no, y_value = tpl_hum)

db.close
```

And MySQL test data table content:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11L6C.png)

and plotly.js

```
    <h1> {{x_value}} Hi There</h1>
    <h1> {{y_value}} Hi There</h1>
    <div id="myPlot" style="width:200;height:800px;"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var x_arry = new Array();
      var y_arry = new Array();
      for(var i = 0; i < {{x_value}}.length; i++){
        x_arry.push({{x_value}}[i]);
      }
      for(var i = 0; i < {{y_value}}.length; i++){
        y_arry.push({{y_value}}[i]);
      }
      
      var data = [{
        x: x_arry,
        y: y_arry,
        mode: "lines"
      }];

      var layout = {
        xaxis:{title:"X: Number"},
        yaxis:{title:"Y: Hum"},
        title:"This is my graph"
      };
      Plotly.newPlot("myPlot", data, layout);
```

I made it like this. But I can't see the plot graph on the web page

[image]

The x_arry value has been output normally in the js code.
However, the plot graph is not drawn on the web page because the y_arry value is not printed. I want to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making two changes to your code.

Firstly, you'll need to convert the `Decimal` values you are getting from the database to Python `float`s, by replacing the line

```py
            tpl_hum.append(value[2])
```

with

```py
            tpl_hum.append(float(value[2]))
```

Secondly, the most reliable way to get data from your Python code to your JavaScript code is to get Python to serialize the data as a JSON string, and put this in your template. Try replacing the following line in your Python code

```py
        return template("index.tpl", x_value = tpl_no, y_value = tpl_hum)
```

with

```py
        json_data = json.dumps({"x_array": tpl_no, "y_array": tpl_hum})
        return template("index.tpl", json_data=json_data)
```

You'll also need to add `import json` to your Python code.

The JavaScript within your template then becomes:

```js
      var jsonData = {{json_data}};
      
      var data = [{
        x: jsonData.x_array,
        y: jsonData.y_array,
        mode: "lines"
      }];

      var layout = {
        xaxis:{title:"X: Number"},
        yaxis:{title:"Y: Hum"},
        title:"This is my graph"
      };
      Plotly.newPlot("myPlot", data, layout);
```

You don't need the loops to read the data into variables such as `x_arry` and `y_arry`. (In fact, it's arguable you wouldn't have needed them before.)

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.